# Flutter how to filter data by 1 value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to filter data in my app but its showing error this is how I am doing.

Its printing `[Instance of 'Post']` now I need to print all values

```
class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {

List showPost;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    print(widget.id);
    showPost = posts.where((i) => i.id == widget.id).toList();
    print(showPost);

  }
```

I need to filter my array which `id` is equal to my `widget.id`

On other file, data look like this

```
final List<Post> posts = [
  Post(
    id: 0,
    authorName: 'Umaiz Khan',
    authorImageUrl: 'assets/images/user0.png',
    timeAgo: '5 min',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/post0.jpg',
  ),
  Post(
    id: 1,
    authorName: 'Saad ahmed',
    authorImageUrl: 'assets/images/user1.png',
    timeAgo: '10 min',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/post1.jpg',
  ),
  Post(
    id: 2,
    authorName: 'Hiba',
    authorImageUrl: 'assets/images/user4.png',
    timeAgo: '10 min',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/post2.jpg',
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the toString() method of your Post class as shown below

```
class Post{
  int id;
  String authorName;
  String authorImageUrl;
  String timeAgo;
  String imageUrl;
  Post({this.id,this.authorName,this.authorImageUrl,this.timeAgo,this.imageUrl});


    @override
  String toString( ) {
    return 'Post{id: $id, authorName: $authorName, authorImageUrl: $authorImageUrl, timeAgo: $timeAgo, imageUrl: $imageUrl}';
  }

}
```

Comment: check the completed code here and check the output in the console https://dartpad.dev/54426eaafb403a8f6f9de7ccc6a6be29

Comment: thanks if possible can you please tell how to print one value also ? print(showPost.toString()); as this is showing whole post if i just need to print authorName . Thanks again

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem just return return 'authorName: $authorName'; in toString() method instead of complete data. If you observe what it is happening in toString() you will find out the answer yourself.

Comment: No i need to show just one value from complete data. In toStrint() its showing all fields which is fine but on first screen where we are calling toString() here need to show just one value from filtered data.

Comment: as we are printing like this print(showPost.toString()); something like print(showPost.toString().authorName); from all values need to show one

Answer (score 1):

Override function *toString* of class Post. return values you need show.

```
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$id - $authorName';
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, not to understand this can you explain a little more how can I add this?

Comment: "Its printing [Instance of 'Post'] now I need to print all values" -> you can try run above code, if working right, I will explain for you :D

Comment: Sorry my mistake i add this at wrong place thanks. Is it possible to print in json format ?

Comment: you can try using jsonEncode on function toString to format json.